# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op

Tags: android

I got this error every time I try to run my android game:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

this is my **build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.play.flyaway"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    buildTypes{}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Any solution to this problem? I already try everything I know of course, but I'm new on this, I really don't know what cause the error apart from what the console says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the following dependency:

```
implementation files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

and also remove the jar from `libs` directory. Then use the matching support library of your compileSdkVersion. So, change the above dependency with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

This is related with [Google play service dependency](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120):

> SDK Version Support in 11.2
>
> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or
>   later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a
>   compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O). This does not change the
>   way your app runs. You will not be required to update
>   targetSdkVersion.

Comment: i include this line in my gradle 
( implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' )

Comment: That "remove the jar from `libs` directory" helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It's about duplicated support library used  :

This dependency:

```
implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
```

is using old version of support library. Try excluding the support library with:

```
implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar'){    
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is caused due to the versions of the support file and plays service.  Update the play service dependencies as per the recommendations(Latest) and sync the project.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used only support:AppCompat, so having this problem
Solved this using 
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:____'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:____'  
 along with AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I already had the jar present in lib/ folder. Deleting it resolved the problem.

So check if you have jar present in any folder:

```
 find . -name *.jar
```

If present in lib folder try deleting it